# Mapbox GL what does ?fresh=true do when loading a tileset?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

Mapbox GL what does ?fresh=true do when loading a tileset? We are having trouble loading the map in a react page. Removing ?fresh=true sometimes breaks the page and other times fixes it. I'm wondering what it does because I can't find anything on it online

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-sdk-js/issues/364#issuecomment-617894314:

> 1. Requests that use this param bypass Mapbox's caching, and request
>    times can therefore be quite a bit slower.
> 2. Requests that use this param have a significantly lower rate limit than cached requests.
>
> There are a few valid use-cases for fresh=true, for example, to
> preview a change in your app if you're co-developing a style and an
> app at the same time, but it should never be used in production / high
> concurrency environments.